# Ajax MySQL query does not return current data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to write an Ajax request that Returns data from a MySQL-database. But it does not work properly, because the Ajax request does not return the current values of the mysql database, if data has changed. Instead it always returns the old data of the database. The php-file is working properly, if I open it in a browser, it shows the correct current data values. I found out, that the Ajax request only shows the correct current data values, if I first open the php-file manually in a browser. If I then again use the ajax request, it returns the correct current data. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for the Ajax request:

```
var scannedTubes = (function() {
  var tmp = null;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "ajaxtest.php",

    success: function(response) {
      alert("RESPONSE: " + response);
      tmp = response;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
  return tmp;
})();
```

The code of the ajaxtest.php file is the following:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("", "root");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "FAIL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }                       

    mysqli_select_db($con, "multitubescan");

    $queryStr = "SELECT code FROM scan WHERE row = 0 AND code <> 'EMPTY'";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);

    $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

    $scannedTubes = "";

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $scannedTubes = $scannedTubes . " " . $data["code"];
    }

    $scannedTubes = $num . " " . $scannedTubes;

    mysqli_close($con);

    echo $scannedTubes;    
?>
```

Comment: try to set ajax cache to false $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); before your ajax request.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose data is cached by your browser. 
Make the url unique:

`url: "ajaxtest.php",`

to

`url: "ajaxtest.php?rnd=" + Math.random() ,`

Comment: jQuery can do that for you: `cache: false` :)